# Mocking methods that call JNI with Mockk

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface, junit4, mockk

I am trying to add unit tests to an existing Android app that has some JNI libraries (only for ARM). I am using `Mockk` and `Junit4`, and I have the following:

This static class is mine, and it calls the `initialize` method of the external SDK (which I was given, I don't have access to their code).

```
internal class DeviceSDK {
    companion object {
        internal fun initialize() {
            val success = ExternalSDK.getInstance().init() // it fails here 2
            return success
        }
    }
}
```

The `init` method calls `loadLibrary` for some native libraries.

In my test class, I have the following:

```
class MyDeviceTest {
    private val sdkInstance = mockk<ExternalSDK>()
   
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mockkStatic(ExternalSDK::class) {
            every { ExternalSDK.getInstance() } returns sdkInstance
        }

        every { sdkInstance.init() } returns true

        mockkStatic(DeviceSDK::class) {
            every { DeviceSDK.initialize() } just runs // it fails here 1
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

This fails where I have put the `it fails here 1` comment, because it calls the line where I put the `it fails here 2` comment, and that tries to load the libraries, giving me an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

But I really don't get why, since in first place I'm mocking the method `DeviceSDK.initialize()` so it should not run. But if it ran, anyway I'm mocking the ExternalSDK `init` method, so that shouldn't run as well.

Is there anything that I'm not getting right? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was because `companion objects` in Kotlin are not actually static classes even though they accomplish the same thing. So you have to change `mockkStatic` for `mockkObject` and then it will not call the SDK.